# Importing Text files and spltting values in a row then assigning each set of values to a tuple , then placing all tuples in a list

Tags: python

I'm still relatively new to python.

I'm a trying to import a text file into a list. I need each line to be contained in a tuple, with the values split
An example of a line looks like this: `1.2 1.7 1.9 2.0`
The code then needs to work with varying dimensions.
what I am after is something like this: `[(1.2,1.4,1.6,2.0),...]`

So far I have managed to get all the values assigned to one tuple, with each line representing one value. But after a few hours, I haven't been able to get any further.

The code I have so far is:

```
def data_import(x):
  data_file = []
  with open(x) as datax:
      lines = datax.readlines()
      lines = [line.rstrip() for line in lines]
      lines = [lines.split(" ",1) for line in lines]
      data_file.append(tuple(lines))
  return data_file
```

this line of code throws an attribute error: " list object has no attribute split". This was when I added the lines.split() to it.

From here I have been stuck, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you update the post with the file `x` (or a subset of it) and the expected output `data_file` (based on `x`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess instead of:

```
    lines = [lines.split(" ", 1) for line in lines]
```

Try:

```
    lines = [line.split(" ", 1) for line in lines]
```

You need to split by the iterator not the full list.

Full code:

```
def data_import(x):
  data_file = []
  with open(x) as datax:
      lines = datax.readlines()
      lines = [line.rstrip() for line in lines]
      lines = [tuple(map(float, lines.split(" "))) for line in lines]
      data_file.extend([lines)
  return data_file
```

Comment: Thats got it going into tuples, I think ive made another error thought. The tuple is now doing want i want it to do, but its only splitting the first value ( a= ( 2.4, 1.5 2.5 )etc..

Comment: @DamoH Edited my answer, it should work now, please accept and upvote if it works :D

Comment: Still doing the same thing. like this: [("6.5","2.5 3.5 4.5")]

Comment: @DamoH Got it! edited my answer, should work now!

Answer (score 0):

Is the below what you are looking for?

```
def data_import(file_name: str):
    data_file = []
    with open(file_name) as f:
        lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
        for line in lines:
            data_file.append(tuple(float(x) for x in line.split()))
    return data_file


print(data_import('input.txt'))
```

input.txt

```
1.2 1.7 1.9 2.0
1.2 1.7 1.9 2.0 67 33
3 6 7
```

output

```
[(1.2, 1.7, 1.9, 2.0), (1.2, 1.7, 1.9, 2.0, 67.0, 33.0), (3.0, 6.0, 7.0)]
```